# Finding the biggest value inside arrays

Tags: arrays, c

[image: What the program needs to do:]

Basically, I need to find the array with the biggest value.
I give the initial point like (3,7), the program looks at the surrounding arrays, picks the biggest one, and does the exact same thing to the selected array too. This loop goes until it finds the biggest array in that area. Please look at the picture for more information

So far I was only able to do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
float Q[10][10]=
{0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,
0.1,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.1,
0.1,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.1,
0.1,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.7,0.7,0.1,
0.1,0.2,0.4,0.4,0.5,0.7,0.7,0.8,0.7,0.1,
0.1,0.2,0.4,0.4,0.5,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.8,0.1,
0.1,0.2,0.4,0.4,0.5,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.4,0.1,
0.1,0.2,0.4,0.4,0.5,0.8,0.8,0.9,1.2,0.1,
0.1,0.2,0.4,0.4,0.5,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.1,0.1,
0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1};

int x0=3, y0=7, i,j;
int x02=x0+2, y02=y0+2;
int x03=x0-2, y03=y0-2;
float small_one=Q[x0][y0], big_one=small_one;

while (x0<x02) {

    x0=x0++;

    if(small_one<Q[x0][y0])
    {
        big_one=Q[x0][y0];
    }
}
while (y0<y02){

    y0=y0++;

     if(small_one<Q[x0][y0])
    {
         big_one=Q[x0][y0];
    }

        printf("&f",big_one); }

return 0;}
```

Comment: Your usage of terminology does not make any sense. You have one multi-dimensional array, or a matrix. It has squares or cells or positions.

Comment: What exactly are `x02` and `x03`? I understand what you're trying to do, but why do you pick variable names that don't make sense? Why are they `2` greater or smaller than `x0`? Why are you only comparing to `x02` and `y02` and not to `x03` or `y03`?

Comment: Can you start by writing a function that compares a square to all 8 surrounding values?

Comment: I compiled your code and got **8** warnings !!! Start fixing them...

Comment: Your code is so far from plausible, and answer to your question might be very close to doing your homework for you, since none of what you have is really usable.  The title makes little sense w.r.t. the assignment.  What you need to find is the largest neighbour, then iterate until there is no longer a largest neighbour.  This is called "_steepest ascent_".

Comment: Start by writing a function that, given the master array, and the current coordinates, looks at the nine entries centred on the current coordinate, and finds the largest one. Realize that if the largest value is the current coordinate, the problem is solved. Take care to correctly handle cases where two values are equal.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things I think you missed..
first, you need to declare your multi-denominational array with {{},{}},

second, every step you act you have to look each side and compare the old value to the point on the square you are just checking,

last is your stop condition: you need to stop where you have no place to proceed to.

note: i didn't done this but you should check your "board" boundary so you will not across it to "the next step

````
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


float ProceedToBiggerElement(float Q[10][10], int *x0, int *y0)
{
    float max = Q[*x0][*y0];
    int x_index = *x0;
    int y_index = *y0;
    int index = 0;
    int j_index = 0;

    for (index = x_index - 1; index <= x_index + 1; ++index)
    {
        for (j_index = y_index - 1; j_index <= y_index + 1; ++j_index)
        {
            if (Q[index][j_index] > max)
            {
                max = Q[index][j_index];
                *x0 = index;
                *y0 = j_index;
            }
        }
    }

    return (max);
}
int main()
{
float Q[10][10]=
{{0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1}, 
{0.1,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.1}, 
{0.1,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.1}, 
{0.1,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.7,0.7,0.1},
{0.1,0.2,0.4,0.4,0.5,0.7,0.7,0.8,0.7,0.1},
{0.1,0.2,0.4,0.4,0.5,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.8,0.1},
{0.1,0.2,0.4,0.4,0.5,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.4,0.1},
{0.1,0.2,0.4,0.4,0.5,0.8,0.8,0.9,1.2,0.1},
{0.1,0.2,0.4,0.4,0.5,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.1,0.1},
{0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1}};

int x0=3, y0=7, i,j;
float new_x0 = 0; float old_x0 = Q[x0][y0];
float init_x0 = old_x0;

while (old_x0 != new_x0)
{
    old_x0 = new_x0;
    new_x0 = ProceedToBiggerElement(Q, &x0, &y0);
}

printf("initiat piont is %f, final point is %f", init_x0, new_x0);

return (0);
}```
````